# Want to create a substring when "," encounters in php

Tags: php, string

I want to create substrings from a string of characters whenever , is encountered in PHP. For example, if Parent string is A, B , C , D then I want to make fours string. String 1 as A, String 2 as B and so on. I am aware of substr function but not sure how to use that so it produces the result I want. Thank you!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$children = explode( ',', $parent );
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php.

Answer (score 1):

You can try php's explode function to achieve this.

```
<?php
  $string = "A,B,C,D"
  explode( ',', $string )
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "a,b,c";
$strings_array = explode( ",", $str );
echo print_r( $strings_array );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to try explode().

```
$string  = "A,B,C,D";
$parts = explode(",", $string);
echo $parts[0]; // A
echo $parts[1]; // B
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explode()` function like following:

```
<?php
$string = 'a,b,c';
$array_of_string = explode(',', $string);
echo $array_of_string[0]; // a
echo $array_of_string[1]; // b
echo $array_of_string[2]; // c
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `explode()` function ! Easy to implement !

ref http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

Use explode:

```
<?php
$string = "A,B,C,D";
$string_array = explode(',',$string);
$stringOne = $string_array[0]; 
$stringTwo = $string_array[1]; 
$stringThree = $string_array[2]; 
$stringFour = $string_array[3]; 
?>
```